# Exclude style property from div

Tags: html, css, properties, styles

I have this div:

**main.css(external)**:

```
#content{
   padding:35px;
}
```

Then I php include another html inside that div:

```
<div id="content"><?php include "news.html"?></div>
```

Inside news.html I want my #poll div to not include padding, when loaded inside #content.

```
#poll{
padding:0px;
}
```

Is that possible? For some reason setting inline css for #poll doesn't work.

Comment: `padding` isn't inherited, so the `div` inserted into this element shouldn't have any padding (unless you've specified it somewhere else). Also, [tag:css] works client-side, so your PHP is irrelevant to the question, what HTML does the PHP produce and send to the browser ('view source')?

Comment: Forget php include, what I wanna do is have 0 padding for the inside div(#poll), although the outer div(#content) has 35px padding. Not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: Nevermind, I just used inline css for that specific page :P Sorry for over-complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative margin on `#poll` to undo the padding of the containing div. See: http://jsfiddle.net/635A4/1/

Also see the comment in the CSS, it's important if you have more elements in the flow that you set a positive bottom margin (and sometimes even top) to make sure the flow doesn't get disturbed.

In fact, I use this a lot to give a content box a padding, but have the block-style title touch the edges anyway without having to use extra wrapper elements.